# How to configure a static ip using netplan for my ethernet over usb in Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

Tags: usb, network-manager, tftp, beagleboard

I am trying to boot my Beaglebone black from network using tftp prototcol.
When starting BBB should see the host as 192.168.7.1.
I tried to edit netplan yaml files but board and PC cannot establish connection.

Here is the debug messages. I am connection through ethernet over  usb
My ubuntu is 20

```
U-Boot SPL 2019.04-g923f8b8 (Jan 02 2022 - 19:05:15 +0000)
Trying to boot from MMC2
Loading Environment from EXT4... 
** Unable to use mmc 0:1 for loading the env **
U-Boot 2019.04-g923f8b8 (Jan 02 2022 - 19:05:15 +0000)
CPU  : AM335X-GP rev 2.1
I2C:   ready
DRAM:  512 MiB
No match for driver 'omap_hsmmc'
No match for driver 'omap_hsmmc'
Some drivers were not found                                                     
Reset Source: Power-on reset has occurred.                                      
RTC 32KCLK Source: External.                                                    
MMC:   OMAP SD/MMC: 0, OMAP SD/MMC: 1                                           
Loading Environment from EXT4...                                                
** Unable to use mmc 0:1 for loading the env **                                 
Board: BeagleBone Black                                                         
<ethaddr> not set. Validating first E-fuse MAC                                  
BeagleBone Black:                                                               
BeagleBone Cape EEPROM: no EEPROM at address: 0x54                              
BeagleBone Cape EEPROM: no EEPROM at address: 0x55                              
BeagleBone Cape EEPROM: no EEPROM at address: 0x56                              
BeagleBone Cape EEPROM: no EEPROM at address: 0x57                              
Net:   eth0: MII MODE                                                           
cpsw, usb_ether                                                                 
Press SPACE to abort autoboot in 0 seconds                                      
board_name=[A335BNLT] ...                                                       
board_rev=[00A5] ...                                                            
switch to partitions #0, OK                                                     
mmc0 is current device                                                          
SD/MMC found on device 0                                                        
switch to partitions #0, OK                                                     
mmc0 is current device                                                          
Scanning mmc 0:1...                                                             
gpio: pin 56 (gpio 56) value is 0                                               
gpio: pin 55 (gpio 55) value is 0                                               
gpio: pin 54 (gpio 54) value is 0                                               
gpio: pin 53 (gpio 53) value is 1                                               
switch to partitions #0, OK                                                     
mmc0 is current device                                                          
gpio: pin 54 (gpio 54) value is 1                                               
Checking for: /uEnv.txt ...                                                     
486 bytes read in 3 ms (158.2 KiB/s)                                            
gpio: pin 55 (gpio 55) value is 1                                               
Loaded environment from /uEnv.txt                                               
Importing environment from mmc ...                                              
Checking if uenvcmd is set ...                                                  
gpio: pin 56 (gpio 56) value is 1                                               
Running uenvcmd ...                                                             
Booting from network ...                                                        
cpsw Waiting for PHY auto negotiation to complete......... TIMEOUT !            
using musb-hdrc, OUT ep1out IN ep1in STATUS ep2in                               
MAC d0:39:72:40:ad:85                                                           
HOST MAC de:ad:be:af:00:00                                                      
RNDIS ready                                                                     
musb-hdrc: peripheral reset irq lost!                                           
high speed config #2: 2 mA, Ethernet Gadget, using RNDIS                        
USB RNDIS network up!                                                           
Using usb_ether device                                                          
TFTP from server 192.168.7.1; our IP address is 192.168.7.2                     
Filename '/var/lib/tftpboot/uImage'.                                            
Load address: 0x82000000                                                        
Loading: 
#### waiting here ......(My Note)
ARP Retry count exceeded; starting again
```

Please help.

Comment: So you're using a Ubuntu Core 20 system?  and not Ubuntu 20.04 LTS  (20 != 20.04)

Comment: Sorry for the missing detail. My OS is "Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS"

Comment: Please correct your question to say so then, Ubuntu has had *year* releases (which are *snap* only) since 2016; where as the *year.month* format products are *deb* based but can also use *snap* packages.  20 & 20.04 are different Ubuntu products.